# why does wxDC::GetTextExtent() return the same value for a high DPI display in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to scale my application written in c++ with wxWidgets for high DPI displays. I am following the guidelines in the [official link](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_high_dpi.html). Everythings work fine so far except the return value of [wxDC::GetTextExtent()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_d_c.html#ae55cbf1bc7b7e836cb192eb48d31efab) function. When I move my window to a monitor with a different DPI, the font size scales but the return value of the wxDC remains the same as before. However if I use [wxWindow::GetTextExtent()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#ac9cd7b4472d5419e518f69311914466f), it returns the correct value! In the document, it says all wxWidgets API use logical pixels but it does not seem so.

In other words, if you try to draw "text" on a device context (dc) in a high DPI display, the drawn text would be small cause the measured value of the font height by wxDC is small ( e.g does not scale ). However all other text drawn by wxWindow scales correctly.

Is this behavior intentional? what should I do to have a correct value? I am using wxWidgets 3.1.5 and Win 10.

Also it is not clear whether wxWidgets use Device Independent Pixels (DIP) or logical Pixels?

Comment: `wxDC` uses logical units (as you mentioned) and `wxWindow` looks like it uses actual pixels. Why would you expect `wxDC::GetTextExtent` to change when DPI changes; isn't the point of logical pixels that it *doesn't* change? Would you mind clarifying what you mean with a reproducible example?

Comment: @ATOMP They said in the doc that "Almost all functions in wxWidgets API take and return values expressed in logical pixels ...". So I assume that the return value of wxWindow and wxDC should be the same.

Comment: `wxWindow` doesn't use logical pixels though; it uses actual pixels, so it should change when DPI changes. (At least, that is my understanding from the documentation)

Comment: @ATOMP So you mean this is a bug in the implementation of `wxWindow` and we should manually fix it? for example by dividing it by scale factor?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug, it seems correct and intentional since it's returning pixels. Not sure if dividing by the scale factor is what you want... could you share your code so people can understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ATOMP I will try to add a simple code but the problem is so simple. If you try to draw "text" on a device context (dc) in a high DPI display, the drawn text would be small cause the measure value of the font height by `wxDC` is small ( e.g does not scale ). However all other text drawn by wxWindow scales correctly.

Comment: @Reza, what wx version do you use? Can you try with (recently released) 3.1.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wxDC::GetTextExtent()` and `wxWindow::GetTextExtent()` should return the same value and if I insert this code in the minimal sample:

```cpp
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    wxLogMessage("wxDC: %d, wxWindow: %d",
                 dc.GetTextExtent("Hello").x,
                 GetTextExtent("Hello").x);
}
```

it displays "wxDC: 28, wxWindow: 28" with default DPI screen and "wxDC: 56, wxWindow: 56" when using 200% DPI scaling with wxWidgets 3.1.6, so you probably just need to update to this release.

Comment: I upgraded to the 3.1.6 and I can confirm your result with the minimal example that I wrote. But my bug still exists. I should inspect more in our code base. Maybe somebody uses the old font or and old device context. Anyway, could you clarify a little bit about when and where wxWidgets uses DIP and logical pixels?

Comment: Please report the bug with a minimal example allowing to reproduce it if you still see it with 3.1.6.